# Only old document types inherit from the Master?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a weird issue here. I noticed I accidentally put some of my document types as children of others, so I removed those and I created brand new document types. These new ones do not inherit from my Master document type, but all of the other ones does. I would love to move away from inheritance and use composition instead, but I think there's a bug going on here.

```
Document Types
    -Master (SEO & Navigation tabs)
    -News
    -About us (Content tab)
    -Members (Content tab)
```

This is the current layout of my document types. `News` and `About us` both have the SEO and Navigation tabs, but the newly created Members does not. How weird is that? I was under the impression that inheritance only worked like this:

```
Document Types
    -Master (SEO & Navigation tabs)
        -News
        -About us (Content tab)
    -Members (Content tab)
```

and then `Members` is free and does not inherit from the Master. I have a feeling that the last one is how my inheritance actually looks, but that there's a bug in the UI. Has anyone experienced this before or know how to solve it? I want to remove the inheritance.

Either this is a bug, or a new update (from 7.6.6 to 7.6.9) changed around all my Document Types, so they're now compositions instead.

Comment: Hmm none of this makes any sense - I trust what you're saying but a screenshot of your structure might help. And are you certain your News and About Us doc types definitely don't inherit from Master?

It certainty seems like a bug otherwise. I recommend looking for an issue on http://issues.umbraco.org, or posting your issue if you can't find one.

Comment: @Harvey They do inherit from it, but not by nested. I have a feeling that the issue is because of a recent 7.6.6 to 7.6.9 upgrade, which apparently moved all my nested document types into compositions instead.